# Push multiple values to stack without using Array or List in C#

Tags: c#, stack

I am trying to do a very simple task in a very stupid and annoying way. I have to read one line of input representing several integers separated by a space.

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

What I want is to reverse them.After I read them `Console.ReadLine();` I try to split them with `.Split()` and after that I want to insert them into a stack. My goal is to reverse them without using List or Array.
Input - 1 2 3 4 5
Output - 5 4 3 2 1
Goal - not to use Array or List but Stacks. This means that I can't `.ToList().ForEach(stackPush())` them. I tried using Select, but for some reason it does not allow me to do the following

```
 string input = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(element=>stackOfNumbers.Push(element));
```

Comment: Impossible since a stack is an array.  The only difference between a stack and an array is a stack you can only access the first location while an array you can access any item.  So you need to redefine you requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = string.Join("", Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).Reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

Select uses IEnumerable behind the scenes, so I think that might not be allowed. This uses only for loops:

```
var a = "1 2 3 4 5";

var stack = new Stack<char>();

for (int i = a.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (a[i] != ' ')
    {
        stack.Push(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for "1 2 3 4 5" but the moment someone enters a bigger number for example 20 30 482 or something like that it won't work so it's not a general solution to my problem.

Comment: Sure. That code compiles, but it it borderline pseudo code. I am sure you will be able to alter it to fit your specific purposes. Just be careful of string.Split(), since it returns an array, and you are not allowed to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "1 29 39 4 59";

            var outputStack = new Stack<string>();

            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            {
                var splitIndex = input.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                if (splitIndex < 0)
                {
                    outputStack.Push(input);
                    input = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    outputStack.Push(input.Substring(0, splitIndex));
                    input = input.Substring(++splitIndex, input.Length - splitIndex);
                }
            }
            while (outputStack.Count > 0)
                Console.WriteLine(outputStack.Pop());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```